# Imported XSLT stylesheet URIs in Saxon 9.8

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I need help in finding a workaround to the following problem and would like to bring this to light in case it's a bug:

I'm currently using `json-doc($url)` to access a web api and use it directly on the xslt stylesheet.

e.g. `json-doc('https://localhost:8443/api/endpoint')`

Everything works great, no problem.

When I use it import the xslt to another stylesheet, that's when things break.

`<xsl:import href="classpath:childthatbreaks.xslt" />`

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unable to load the resource 
[classpath:https://localhost:8443/api/endpoint] using the thread context class loader or the current class's class loader
at net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardUnparsedTextResolver.resolve(StandardUnparsedTextResolver.java:184) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.functions.UnparsedTextFunction.readFile(UnparsedTextFunction.java:76) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.functions.UnparsedText.evalUnparsedText(UnparsedText.java:89) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.functions.UnparsedText.call(UnparsedText.java:43) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.functions.UnparsedText.call(UnparsedText.java:29) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.FunctionCall.iterate(FunctionCall.java:547) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.CardinalityChecker.evaluateItem(CardinalityChecker.java:280) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.Evaluator$3.evaluate(Evaluator.java:73) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.Evaluator$3.evaluate(Evaluator.java:70) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.SystemFunctionCall.evaluateArguments(SystemFunctionCall.java:434) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.FunctionCall.iterate(FunctionCall.java:545) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.CopyOf.processLeavingTail(CopyOf.java:557) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:880) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:699) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:687) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NamedTemplate.expand(NamedTemplate.java:262) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-5.jar:na]
```

It seems the xslt parser is trying to build an absolute URI out of an already absolute URI by prepending `classpath:`

According to spec,

> If the URI is a relative URI reference, then it is resolved relative to the >static base URI property from the static context.

which clearly wasn't the behavior I encountered.

Putting the function call in the topmost stylesheet is not an option because we plan to use this as a standard utility stylesheet/library.

I'm currently using Saxon-HE 9.8.0-5

Comment: Is that the ENTIRE stack trace, including all "caused by" sections?

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison I updated the stack trace to put some context to the problem. I was trying to look for the code that prepended "classpath:" and the function call `parse-json(unparsed-text($uri))` brought me here. It seems the culprit is at line 98 of `UnparsedTextFunction` `absoluteURI = ResolveURI.makeAbsolute(href, baseURI);`

Comment: Is `<xsl:import href="classpath:childthatbreaks.xslt" />` what you use in your XSLT code? Why not `<xsl:import href="childthatbreaks.xslt" />`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I would if I had an external template repository. but this resource is packaged in a JAR as part of a Spring Boot application. Is your suggestion possible in this scenario?

Comment: I am not really familiar with how such URLs should be resolved, I guess you have to wait until Michael Kay from Saxonica picks up your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace shown is from a call on the `unparsed-text()` function: that's because `json-doc()` is implemented as the composition `unparsed-text() => parse-json()`.

I think you're right though. Saxon special-cases classpath: URIs, because they are non-standard and not properly handled by the java.net.URI class, and if the base URI starts with "classpath:" then it's prepending "classpath:" to the supplied URI without first checking that the supplied URI is relative.

You can track this issue at

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3518